# ContentVersion: how to check File Type and File Size?

Tags: apex, contentversion

I need to check Max Image Size and File Type so I can display the correct error in `ApexPages.Messages`. I tried to do something like this:

```
if (conVer.FileType != '')
```

But I don't know what FileType values I can use.

Comment: `public ContentVersion conVer {get; set;}` `private static final Integer IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1048576;` `if (conVer.ContentSize > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) { do }` But it's not worked

Comment: `if (conVer.FileExtension == 'jpg') { do }` It's not worked too

Answer (score 1):

You can use values like "WORD_X" or "PDF" or etc.  The easiest way I've found is to upload a file, and then check the FileExtension field on ContentVersion or ContentDocument.

More details here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentDocument.htm